# peer js deleting text when live

Tags: peerjs

i created a live sharing text editor which permits people to edit a shared document, so as a user types on one end, the other sees on the other, but when the user deletes on one end it doesnt delete on the other, how can i solve this problem such when the user deletes a text on one end it deletes on the other, so far here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Live Text Sharing</title>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.peerjs.com/0.3/peer.js"></script>
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var conn;
    var peer = new Peer({key: '5nyu3ci7jomq85mi'});
    peer.on('open', function (id){
        $('#pid').text(id);
    });

    peer.on('connection', connect);
    function connect(c){
        conn=c;
        $('#rid').val(conn.peer);
        $('#rid').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#progBar').width('100%');
        conn.on('data', function (data){
            $('#inputText').val($('#inputText').val()+data);
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#connect').click(function(){
            $('#progBar').width('100%');
            var c=peer.connect($('#rid').val());
            c.on('open', function(){
                connect(c);
            });
        });

        $('#inputText').keypress(function (e){

            var ev= e || window.event;
            var asciikey=ev.keyCode || ev.which;
            text= String.fromCharCode(asciikey);
            conn.send(text);

        });

    });

    </script>
    <h2 style='margin-left: 30%;'> Live Text Sharing</h2>
    Your peerJS id is : <span id='pid'></span><br><br>
    Connect to peer: <input type='text' id='rid' placeholder="someone else's id" >
        <input type='button' value="Connect" id="connect">
        <input type='button' value='Disconnect' id='disconnect'>
        <br>
        <br>

    <div class="progress progress-striped active" style='width: 25%;'>
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" id='progBar' style="width: 0%;">
        </div>
    </div>

    <textarea id='inputText' rows='30' style="width: 45%; margin-left: 20%;">

    </textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think think that the problem maybe is that you send the character itself. So when the one participant press 'a' the other participant receives 'a'. But when the first one press delete the second one receives ' ' ..!! Probably you have to send the ASCII code and handle it differently when it receives different codes..

Also I see that this doesn't handle the arrow keys. So if you want to add smth in the middle of the text you just can't..

hoping that helped a little bit..